# Change user password in child system remotely from CUA

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-basis

I am trying to find a solution which will allow me to change a user's password from our Central User Administration (CUA) system where the user's access and password is on the child system.

I tried to use BAPI_USER_CHANGE with destination call but it doest suit in my case.
(we locked change password function in child systems). This is my code with destination call

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_USER_CHANGE'
DESTINATION 'CLNT_500'
  EXPORTING
     username  = p_bname
     password  = wa_password
     passwordx = wa_passwordx
  TABLES
     return    = it_return.
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Which kind of central user administration system are we talking about - the one outlined in http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp1/helpdata/en/bf/b0b13bb3acd607e10000000a11402f/frameset.htm ?

Comment: And the most important question... Why do you try to work around this central management system and assign the password programmatically? :)

Answer (score 0):

We tried to do something similar a while ago, and we ended up doing it in two steps:

- `BAPI_USER_CHANGE` sets an initial password for the user
- `SUSR_USER_CHANGE_PASSWORD_RFC` sets a productive password. It needs the old password as a parameter, that's why we needed to call `BAPI_USER_CHANGE` first.